# Exclamation point icons appeared next to two disabled Gnome Shell extensions

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

Two exclamation point icons appeared in the Tweaks (*gnome-tweaks*) application when Extensions was selected in the left pane as shown in the below screenshot. There are two triangular exclamation point icons to the right of the following two disabled GNOME Shell extensions.

- Sensors
- Ubuntu Dock

When I click on either of the two exclamation point icons the Ubuntu Software app opens, but Sensors and Ubuntu Dock remain disabled.

[image]

The settings for Sensors and Ubuntu Dock extensions in Tweaks are both stuck at disabled. I tried to enable the Sensors and Ubuntu Dock extensions by moving their sliders from OFF to ON in the Tweaks application, but I wasn't able to enable either of them.

Comment: Please click on `edit` above on the left and advise if you are asking about the SENSORS or the UBUNTU DOCK item as there are two exclamation warning symbols above.

Comment: When I click on exclamation marker jump ubuntu software center

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve? (Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The warning notification icon next to Ubuntu Dock may be caused by a conflict with Dash to Dock GNOME Shell extension. This extension is a modified version of Dash to Dock with different defaults. Dash to Dock can be installed to replace it and give more (but unsupported) configuration options.

This warning notification will disappear if you uninstall the redundant Ubuntu Dock GNOME Shell extension with the following command:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock  
setsid gnome-shell --replace # Press the Enter key again before closing the terminal.
```

---

You also have a warning notification in Tweaks application -> Extensions about a possible problem with the Sensors GNOME Shell extension. Uninstall the Sensors GNOME Shell extension in Ubuntu Software and install Psensor instead. Psensor is almost identical to Sensors in appearance and functionality.

```
sudo apt install psensor
```

Psensor displays itself on the desktop as a little thermometer icon in the notification area in the upper right corner of the desktop. You can right-click the thermometer icon at any time to display the hardware temperatures.